# How do I use preg_match for my case?

Tags: php, html

I have this output with a command :

```
can0 02001600 [2] 00 00 can0 07001600 [2] 00 00 can0 11001600 [2] 5C A7
```

It's not every time in the same order, it can be :

```
can0 11001600 [2] 5C A7 can0 02001600 [2] 00 00 can0 07001600 [2] 00 00
```

"5C A7".
I do this :

```
preg_match("11001600 [2] [A-Z0-9]",$output);
```

But it gives me 0 so it means that it doesn't found. How do I do ?

Comment: you are missing some basic concepts about the PCRE, go with the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) and read about patterns

Comment: @Zekeriya Looking at your previous questions, you seem to be one of those that never accepts an answer. Both the answers below does what you need. Maybe you just need help with it. Read here how to and why to accept answers https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.
The `[` is a regex char and needs to be escaped to be used as a string in the regex.

https://regex101.com/r/Dm12mr/2

`/11001600 \[2\] ([A-Z0-9]{2} [A-Z0-9]{2})/` works

EDIT: Forgot the ()

Answer (score 1):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/807380)

**Regex:** `11001600 \[2\]\s+\K[A-Z0-9]{2}\s+[A-Z0-9]{2}`

> **1.** `11001600 \[2\]\s+\K` this will match `11001600 [2]` `\K` will reset current match.
>
> **2.** `[A-Z0-9]{2}\s+[A-Z0-9]{2}` this will match `A-Z`,`0-9` and `{2}` is for two times.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string="can0 11001600 [2] 5C A7 can0 02001600 [2] 00 00 can0 07001600 [2] 00 00 ";

preg_match("/11001600 \[2\]\s+\K[A-Z0-9]{2}\s+[A-Z0-9]{2}/",$string,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Output:** `5C A7`

Comment: @Andreas sorry for that.